# How to create a vhost for magento store in xampp

Tags: magento-1.9

How do I create a **vhost** in **xampp** for multiple websites?

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is create a virtualhosts for multiple Website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento_path"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento_path">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain2.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento_path"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento_path">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain3.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento_path"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento_path">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You have 2 options, addd ServerAlias for diferent urls of each website or you can create differents vritualhost

And also the .htaccess file in your Magento root directory:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1_com
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1_com
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2_com
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2_com
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www\.domain3\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain3_com
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain3\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain3\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain3_com
SetEnvIf Host ^domain3\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

The `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` you need get from your Store Configuration: System -> Manage Stores